# Draw 4 Circles on Screen in Square Formation

Tags: python, graphics

How can I create 4 balls using the `Circle` class? I need the four balls to appear on the screen in a square formation.

```
ball=[1,2,3,4];
for ball in range(0,4):
    ball=Circle(Point(FieldWidth//2,FieldHeight//2),BallSize);
    ball.setFill("red");
    ball.draw(Field);
ball1=Circle(Point(FieldWidth//2,FieldHeight//2),BallSize);
ball.setFill("red");
ball.draw(Field);
```

Comment: You can't name several different things the same name like this, you are going to get some odd results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
# make a list of balls
balls = []
for i in range(4):
    ball=Circle(Point(FieldWidth//2,FieldHeight//2),BallSize)
    ball.setFill("red")
    ball.draw(Field)
    balls.append(ball) # put ball into balls list

# do stuff to a single ball 
ball[2].setFill("red")

# do stuff to all balls
for ball in balls:
    ball.setFill("red")
```

Comment: How'd you go, any luck with this @Nick Funchion?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to create 4 instance of the `Circle` class.

```
balls = list()
for _ in range(4):
    ball=Circle(Point(FieldWidth//2,FieldHeight//2),BallSize)
    ball.setFill("red")
    ball.draw(Field)
    balls.append(ball)
```

This will create 4 instances of `Circle` and store them in a list so you can access them later if necessary.

Alternatively you create a list of `balls` first and then edit them later on:

```
balls = [Circle(Point(FieldWidth//2,FieldHeight//2),BallSize) for _ in range(4)]
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
for idx, color in enumerate(colors):
    balls[idx].setFill(color)
```

Comment: i am not sure why but it will not create the 4 balls. I need the four balls to appear on the screen in a square formation.

Comment: You're giving each ball the same x, y position so they will overlap.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I'm not familiar with the library he is using for the points. So @NickFunchion your problem is not what you had in the OP you need a way to place the balls on screen in a square.

Comment: @NickFunchion I have clarified your post as best I could with the info but you will need to edit it further. Do you want the balls in the middle of the screen? Where should the center of the formation be? We will need more info to help you.